# Change language from an activity that reflects in previously created activities as well

Tags: android, localization

I am using two buttons to change the language in my app. There are two activities and both of them have the language changing buttons.

The problem is that when I move to the second activity from the first then change the language the first one is still in the old language. The onCreate is not called since it was not killed.
I am going to make more activities as well, I do not want to finish and start acitivities while moving within the app to call the onCreate. How do change the language without having to recreate the activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try calling onConfigurationChanged "manually" from your activity:

```
Resources res = getResources();
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.locale = newLocale;
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
onConfigurationChanged(conf);
```

Also declare in AndroidManifest for your activity:

```
android:configChanges="locale"
```

Comment: I did it. I check the language onResume and change it. Its working properly thank you for your answer

Comment: Great! Glad i could help!